# How to add detect button presses in tvOS?

Tags: swift, apple-tv, tvos

I have follow this [tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-tvos-apps-for-apple-tv-with-swift/) and everything works fine. The only issue I'm having is i can't figure out how to detect when a button has been pressed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html)?

Comment: Yes @DanielStorm, I now have a `pressesEnded` function which never gets called for some reasom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of the tutorial here, the method of adding interactivity to TVML-based apps is to use addEventListener on the DOM element in question. You can find the DOM element by holding a reference to it during creation, or by using getElementById or other such similar JavaScript DOM techniques. Also, I should mention I've added a "Part 2" to the mentioned tutorial which includes this as it's primary focus.

Here's an example of how you might do this in JS, assuming myDOMElement is a variable that references your button as a DOM element.

```
  myDOMElement.addEventListener("select", function() { alert("CLICK!") }, false);
```

I have more info on the tutorial of course, so feel free to [check that out](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-tvos-apps-for-apple-tv-part-2/), too.

Comment: Thank you @jameson! Works perfectly, thanks for the tutorials as well :-)

Comment: The templates I've seen don't have it but you can definitely add an event listener for `play` to detect the Play/Pause button being pressed.

Comment: hello there, if my document has two buttons, OK and cancel, how can I detect clicking one of them? new to JS

Answer (score 2):

Button presses are similar to UITouch events. Take a look at the UIPressEvent callbacks in the UIResponder header. UIViewControllers are part of the responder chain, so you can add the callbacks in your view controller similar to this:

```
- (void)pressesEnded:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event {

    UIPress *anyPress = [presses anyObject];
    // handle press event

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I now have this function that isn't getting called, do you know why?

Comment: `override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        let press = UIPress()
        abort()
    }`

Comment: I am trying to handle the touch of a UIButton on tvOS with that method, but it does not work. Should it not intercept the touch of a button, as I am using UIPressEventSelect to select a button?

Answer (score 2):

```
let playPauseRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "playPauseRecognizer:")
playPauseRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer:UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)]

     view.addGestureRecognizer(playPauseRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using "UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside" on tvOS, since that doesn't do what you might expect: you probably want to use "UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered" instead.

TouchUpInside is triggered by actual touches, which isn't really what you wanted here: if you want the Select button press on the remote to trigger your button, you should use PrimaryActionTriggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can add action to a UIButton same as iOS, according to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815)

> An instance of the UIButton class implements a button on the touch
>   screen. A button intercepts touch events and sends an action message
>   to a target object when tapped. Methods for setting the target and
>   action are inherited from UIControl. This class provides methods for
>   setting the title, image, and other appearance properties of a button.
>   By using these accessors, you can specify a different appearance for
>   each button state.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of @jess-bowers code:

```
override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    let anyPress: UIPress? = presses.first
}
```