# How to listen for Button KeyPresses in Android/IOS for Nativescript/Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

Im trying to navigate between buttons with Keys(DPAD) so i need to listen for KeyEvents

I Solved it for Android i just don't know how to do it in IOS

```
public onButtonLoaded_1(args) {
    let btn = args.object as Button;
    let androidButton = btn.android as android.widget.Button

    androidButton.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener({
        onKey: function (view, keyCode, keyEvent) {
          if (
            keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER &&
            keyEvent.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
          ) {
            console.log("DPAD Center Pressed");
          }
            

            return false;
        }
    }))
 
  }
```

It does not work for Volmue Up and Down in Emulator i did not testet in a Device.
######################################################################

**For IOS I have no Idea how to do it, i foud this maybe someone knows hot make it happen in IOS**

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-keyboard-input-using-pressesbegan-and-pressesended

[How to add detect button presses in tvOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502963/how-to-add-detect-button-presses-in-tvos)

[How to handle Menu Button action in tvOS remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634638/how-to-handle-menu-button-action-in-tvos-remote)

[How to detect a 'Click' gesture in SwiftUI tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200396/how-to-detect-a-click-gesture-in-swiftui-tvos)

Swift Keyboard Keycodes

https://gist.github.com/swillits/df648e87016772c7f7e5dbed2b345066

Comment: Why are you trying to write native code? Why don't you use angular's key events such as `(keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"`?

Comment: ohhh, but do u catch ios keys can u show me or volume up down  ?

Comment: Did you try logging the key events and checking their content for a 'keycode' property?

Comment: i just testet in androidtv emulator , i does not seem is working so, if someone knows how to do it with native code please help me :)